# How do I control the color the trace on VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, customization

I'm using a dark colored theme on VS2010, but I get the following when I'm tracing the code. Moving between stack trace points auto-selects the calling code and highlights it in the following way.

A screenshot is here: http://picpaste.com/vs2010_trace-zPXJFz8y.jpg
I couldn't post the pic here since I'm a new user...

I have looked on all Fonts & Colors settings but cannot find the correct one to change this.

Any ideas?

Comment: when changing the colors of the editor in visual studio, it sometimes helps to start with a scheme from http://studiostyl.es/. Most of them have the correct settings for the tracing included, and then you can adapt the scheme to fit your needs.

Comment: @Roel I did.. and still this was a problem. Well, to be honest, there were many other problems with it. As Lang said, it seems people doing those don't need to read the code :) So I have fixed all I found except this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out which one was the correct item I was after:

`Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors -> Read-Only Region`

Even though I tried to change a lot of them already, I had not considered the *Read-Only Region* as a possible suspect. Only after the suggestion from C. Lang I tried these that I had sort of marked as "not related".

Anyway, thanks and this dark theme is again usable to read code :)